# What logic error could be leading to a runtime error here?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I have a piece of code that prints the steps of the Insertion Sort algorithm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        Func<int[], string> IntArrayToString = (x) => string.Join(" ", Array.ConvertAll(x, k => k.ToString()));
        for(int i = arr.Length - 2, last = arr[arr.Length - 1]; ; --i)
        {
            if(arr[i] > last)
            {
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i]; 
                Console.WriteLine(IntArrayToString(arr));
            }                
            else
            {
                arr[i + 1] = last;
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(IntArrayToString(arr));
    }
}
```

as per [this challenge problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertionsort1?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) and on one of the 4 test I'm getting a runtime error. Problem is, I can't see what the runtime error or test case is (unless I actually purchase an account on the site). So I must guess-and-check or think through the problem. I already tried adding a

```
if(arr.Length < 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IntArrayToString(arr));
    return;
}
```

before the loop but still getting an error.

Comment: have you verified if your array is empty before indexing it?

Comment: you can install elmah and see there error there. alse usefull for other errors which you never expect

Comment: could you not just wrap the whole thing in a Try..Catch block and do Console.WriteLine in the Catch block to find out what the error is? (For debugging purposes only)

Comment: Your for loop doesn't guard against `i` dropping below zero.

Comment: this is the testcase that your code is failing:
First Line: 10   Second Line: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1

// I purchased it for free

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli so IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `for` loop, it can easily be seen that if there is no value less or equal to the `last`, the `break` will never hit, and when `i` becomes `-1`, you 'll get `IndexOfRangeExpection`.

The correct algorithm requires both `i` and `last` to be defined outside of the loop. For instance, like this:

```
int i = arr.Length - 1;
int last = arr[i];
while (--i >= 0 && arr[i] > last)
{
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    Console.WriteLine(IntArrayToString(arr));
}
arr[i + 1] = last;
```

Of course there are other corner cases like `arr.Length < 2`, but I think the challenge excludes such possibilities.